# How to calculate numbers(in string format) in the XML file

Tags: r, converters

I have following XML data and I would like to do a calculation

```
<data>
    <numbers>
        <value>1 - 3</value>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
        <value>5 - 10</value>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
        <value>2.4 +/- 3.2</value>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
        <value>10</value>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>...</numbers>
    <numbers>...</numbers>
    <numbers>...</numbers>
    ...
</data>
```

As above, there has 2 problems, one is the values are in string format and another problem is there has different type of values, some are using +/-, some are using range.

logically I know how to do it, just use if-else to detect different format such as:

```
if (tag "value" contains "+/-"):
    Separate the string by "+/-", convert the number from string to number
    use first number + last number to find the biggest number
    use first number - last number to find the smallest number

if (tag "value" contains "-"):
    Separate the string by "-", convert the number from string to number
    first number is smallest number, last number is biggest number

if (tag "value" contains a "whole number"):
    Just convert it into number format and done.
```

This is how the programming look like, I'm a student and I'm currently self-studying R language, I have idea on how to do it but I don't know how to code it, maybe there has some libs or functions to do it.

if you know how to do it please kindly help me on this, thank you very much and I'm really appreciate your help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
h <- "<data>
  <numbers>
  <value>1 - 3</value>
  </numbers>
  <numbers>
  <value>5 - 10</value>
  </numbers>
  <numbers>
  <value>2.4 +/- 3.2</value>
  </numbers>
  <numbers>
  <value>10</value>
  </numbers>
</data>
"
h <- XML::xmlParse(h)
v <- XML::xpathSApply(h, "//value", XML::xmlValue)
lapply(v, function(x) {
  if (stringr::str_detect(x,"\\+/-")) {
    num1 <- stringr::str_extract(x, ".+(?=\\+/-)")
    num2 <- stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=\\+/-).+")

    list(
      "+" = sum(as.numeric(c(num1, num2))),
      "-" = diff(as.numeric(c(num1, num2)))
    )
  } else {
    eval(parse(text=v[1]))
  }
})
```